# vbc.exe error when switching to MS Office late binding

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I need to program a little MS Word functionality and I do not know if the user is running Office 2010, 2013 or 2016.
So I decided to switch from early binding to late binding.
The (working) early binding code is:

```
Dim oWord As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("test.doc")
txtText1.Text = oDoc.FormFields("Text1").Result
oDoc.Close(False)
oWord.Quit(False)
```

Used references:

```
Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library
```

For switching to late binding I removed the two reference and change the code to

```
Dim oWord As Object
Dim oDoc As Object
oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("test.doc")
txtText1.Text = oDoc.FormFields("Text1").Result
oDoc.Close(False)
oWord.Quit(False)
```

When I compile my project Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1 throws the error:

> "vbc.exe" wurde mit dem Code -2146232797 beendet.

which might be in english:

> "vbc.exe" ended with the code -2146232797

What do I have to change to let VS compile using late binding against Word?

Update: When I add the references and use the code "late binding" (..as Object) VS compiles.

Comment: -2146232797 == 0x80131623 == COR_E_FAILFAST == Environment.FailFast().  The Roslyn integration is a massive bag 'o bugs, add this one to the heap by clicking the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues).  You do need to provide better repro code btw, what you posted here doesn't cut it.

Comment: Better repro code? I can reproduce the error when pasting above code in the FormLoad event of the main form. The rest code is generated by VS - you mean that generated code? And what do I anser at "**Version Used**" ? I do not know which version my VS uses (how do I retrieve the version of that "roslyn" - what ever that is?)

Comment: Does your project use Option Strict On? Try turning it off and see if that makes a difference. As I recall, VB.NET has to be handled like C# if that's activated, meaning you need to use PInvoke (GetType().InvokeMember) for late-binding.

Comment: There should not be a need for you to use late binding in this case. Did you try running your first sample against the three Office versions? Just make sure that you deploy the PIA.

Comment: Well, that is strange. Yesterday I rebootet my machine several times. Now my code works without any changes: I referenced to Office 16 again to reproduce the error message and my code runs on Office 2016 AND on Office 2010. I will investigate further to understand what's going on.